# outlook vba code to display pictures in email

Tags: vba, email, outlook

By default, my MS Outlook 2013 is set NOT to download images in received HTML e-mail messages. I would like to keep this setting.

There are some senders whose emails are handled by my Outlook VBA code...and filed into specific folders (rather than the INBOX). I do not use the in-built RULES.

These are known senders...and I would like to have the pictures in the emails from these SELECT KNOWN senders downloaded and displayed. I could do this manually for each email... by right clicking etc... but that is a pain... when there are many such emails.

I am unable to figure out the few lines of code (one line ?) required to download / enable display of images / pictures in the email. Something like...    MailItem.Display     (which does not work... it only displays the mail in an independent window)... or     MailItem.DisplayImages    (that is not a known method!).

I would include this one line (or lines) in the routine which handles emails from some known senders....so that their emails always have images / pictures downloaded and displayed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set the `PidTagBlockStatus` property - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee219242(v=exchg.80).aspx.

Note that while you can read/write that property using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`, you will not be able to calculate its value correctly - Outlook Object Model rounds off the value of the message delivery time, and you would need the raw Extended MAPI value (accessible in C++ or Delphi only) as the `FileTime` structure.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it exposes the [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`DownloadPictures` property. Something like the following should do the job (VB script):

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set Item = Session.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(YourOutlookItem)
  Item.DownloadPictures = true
  Item.Save
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for that.